# Eclipse 2019-03 failing to run certain JUnit 4 tests from the Window but not Test suites or run configuration

Tags: eclipse, junit, junit4, java-11, eclipse-2019-03

I have installed Eclipse 2019-03 from both the installer and tar ball. Certain JUnit test will run from a "run as" selection in the window and others will not. The ones that will not run will run:

- Test suite that includes the test class
- Run -> run configurations
- You can also run it from the JUnit view either from a test suite or run it again.

I have tried deleting then adding the code back in then which seems to work but then fails again in future.

I have tried re-installing eclipse and then adding the src and pom to the maven project and the issue is still there.

Any suggestions?

2019-06-28:

It seems there are also issues with this version of eclipse finding the main method in my Main class. Although removing or changing the code did resolve the issue there were a number of other issues croping up. I tried again to resolve this using both a new "run configuration" and run "Java Application". Both fail to find the class. This is a very simple Java 11 maven projet and I do not see why it is having these issues.

At this point I am going to roll back to a previous version of eclipse to see if it is having similar issues with this code.

2019-06-28 NEW:

Rolling back to photon resolved the issues with both running the code and the junit issues.

Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200

Comment: It seems that the critical line is: verify(geneTissueReader, times(1)).getGeneTissuesMap(); This line is the issue I am trying to figure out why.

Comment: Nothing in the mockito documentation suggests and explanation.

Comment: What error message do you get for test cases that "will not run will run"? If you want to add information please edit your question. Don't use the comments for this purpose.